# How can i show unicode string in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

On my development PC i have windows 8 64bit. Here i can see Unicode string and also can print it using crystal report.

But when i install my app to other PC (Windows 7 32 Bit) i see square boxes instead of Unicode string.

Then i open notepad (On other pc) and change the font as same font i used in crystal report which is Cambria.

In notepad i can write Unicode characters, no problem there.
But in crystal report why i am seeing square boxes?

## Any suggestion?

In crystal report i used label for displaying Unicode string.

### EDIT

I am using NVARCHAR as storage data type in MS SQL SERVER Local DB. Now i store unicode string data using N'UnicodeString'. After insertion i run a select query and see all record are fine and no unicode display problem. 
Make a dataset and create a crystal report with it. 
Run and print crystal report.
Every thing is fine (Development PC).

Now after production i transfer my exe to another pc running on Windows 7 32 bit and run it. All things are okey excepts the unicode characters they became boxes.

Comment: Probably the problem is in data storage, for example data type of the column in database table, should be `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Yes i am using NVARCHAR please read my full question. I can see unicode string on my development PC but not in client's PC

Comment: Seeing strings correctly in your development client doesn't mean you are using `NVARCHAR` and you didn't mentioned in your question that you have used `NVARCHAR` as data type of columns. So if your column types are `NVARCHAR` please edit the question and say something about it.

Comment: Isn't this to do with the installed fonts? ie you have a font installed on your dev machine that includes glyphs for the unicode strings, whereas the target machine doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems my problem is solved. Actually in my clients PC another software called AVRO Keyboard is installed previously. And for this reason i am getting this font problem.

I installed Windows 7 64 and 32 bit respectively in Virtual PC and test my app on both of them and get no problem on font.

Answer (score 0):

@Tanmay Majumder,  this is only font Problem.

Setup your desire font on your Client PC.
And type Notepad As like (স্টোর কপি) Now Copy and Past in Crystal Report. and change Font Name as like (Bangla).

C this way- [image: Unicode in Crystal Report]